# Tag first (or n-th) observation of group

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data:

```
DT = data.table(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3), Y = c(2001, 2002, 1999, 2001, 2001, 2002))

DT
   ID  Y
1:  1 2001
2:  1 2002
3:  2 1999
4:  3 2001
5:  3 2001
6:  3 2002
```

the unique key of the dataset is `ID` and `Y`. I would like to create a variable `first` that equals 1 for the first observation of the group, `data.table` way, as defined by the key:

```
DT
   ID  Y    first
1:  1 2001    1
2:  1 2002    0
3:  2 1999    1
4:  3 2001    1
5:  3 2001    1
6:  3 2002    0
```

I was trying to do something with `.I[1L]` but couldn't figure out. Additionally, a bonus question would be to create such a variable for the `n`-th observation (assuming that `n <` max number of obs. in all groups). Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try `head`

```
DT[,first := +(Y==head(Y,1)), by = ID]
```

or a more compact one (thank @akrun)

```
DT[, first := +(Y == Y[1]), ID]
```

or a more general one (thank @akrun again)

```
library(dplyr)
DT[, first := +(Y %in% nth(Y, 1)), by = ID]
```

which gives

```
> DT
   ID    Y first
1:  1 2001     1
2:  1 2002     0
3:  2 1999     1
4:  3 2001     1
5:  3 2001     1
6:  3 2002     0
```

Comment: @akrun Thanks! Yes it is more compact :)

Comment: @akrun That is a more general solution, thanks again!

Comment: Thank you! How would you go for a group that involves more than 1 variable?

Comment: @vog We can use `.(a,b,c)` for example

Comment: That's not working in my df. Might it be cause my grouping variables are characters?

Comment: @vog post your question and show details.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rleid` :

```
library(data.table)
n <- 1

DT[, first := as.integer(rleid(Y) == n), ID]

#   ID    Y first
#1:  1 2001     1
#2:  1 2002     0
#3:  2 1999     1
#4:  3 2001     1
#5:  3 2001     1
#6:  3 2002     0
```